# Is there any alternative to <div> that will accept focus?

Tags: html, accessibility

Is there any alternative to `<div>`? My website is losing "accessibility" because I cannot set focus on a `<div>`. What control should I use in order to replicate `<div>` and still hold focus?

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div style="height:70px; overflow:hidden" id="divMsg">
   <div class="DivClass">abcdefg abcdkfjghfjdfkj</div><br>
   <div class="DivClass">abcdefg abcdkfjghfjdfkj</div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but if you give the `div` a `tabindex` attribute, it will be "focusable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add tabindex to make it focusable; however, this is usually not enough. If you want the element to be clickable, you will also need to add a keydown or keypress handler so that the user can activate it using ENTER, similar to a A link. Otherwise the user will be able to tab to it, but may not be able to do anything with the link after.

If you are trying to create a clickable element, it is sometimes simpler to start with a A tag, and then style it so that doesn't look like a link. A elements respond to both keyboard and mouse and fire onclick for both, so you don't have to do additional keyboard input handing like you do with a DIV.

Finally, if you are making a DIV or A that visually looks like a button or some other control, add the appropriate ARIA role so that a screenreader will call out the appropriate element type - eg.

```
<a HREF="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dosomething()" role="button">Complete Transaction</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a `tabindex` attribute.

Comment: tabindex is part of the answer, but might not be enough depending on what the OP is trying to do; div's onclick only responds to mouse, so keydown/keypress handler may also be needed so that keyboard users can 'click' the element. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking for accessibility, try out the new HTML 5 tags like `<article>`. So for example a textreader knows what to read, and your page is much better structured.

Check out this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, it depends why you are using the div; I'm guessing for layout. The tab ordering is dependent upon more than tabindex, as defaults and overflow affects positioning and focus.

To be more specific, you won't use a div to latch onto for tabindex. Rely upon JavaScript and a unique ID; `<div class="content" id="page1">`

This will also provide you an anchor so you could use `http://index.html#divMsg` to link focus to the exact place in your HTML document. Note you have only one div ID and reuse the same div class twice in your example.
[If this is all new to you the article on difference between ID and CLASS may be of interest to you](http://css-tricks.com/818-the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 0):

**Links** (element a) and **form elements** (input text and alike, file, radio and checkbox, submit, image and type button, select, textarea, button element, etc) are focusable by default.
Thumb rule: if an element does something, it should be a link or a form element part of a form. (OT: *I guess I've a problem with conjugation here but can't find exactly what - english isn't my mothertongue*)

Think twice (at least :)) before using the tabindex attribute: it'll work for a while in your project and then you make some modification elsewhere and suddenly all is broken. And it'll break again, again and again.

For testing with Safari, you'll need to modify Preferences: this browser (maybe also Chrome?) only cycle by default through form elements and not links. Users of keyboard cycle through every focusable elements I guess, like in IE and Firefox.

To learn further, Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.0 (WCAG 2.0) have Sufficient Techniques (and "Failure(s)" also) about **[keyboard](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/20100729/#keyboard-operation)** use.